# How to do vice versa replacement via regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Lets say i want to replace the word "apple" with "orange" and the word "orange" with "apple" how do i do that in Perl via regex?

Here's my code which i have no luck with:

```
while (<MYFILE>) {
    if (/apple/i) {
        s/$&/orange/i;
    }

    if(/orange/i) {
        s/$&/apple/i;
    }
}
```

That above code would work i think if there's somehow a way to terminate the if function if it is succesful and dont execute anymore code forcing it to return to the while loop. But im sure there's a simple regex way of doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, *never* use the `$&` variable: it slows down the regex engine. Also, you don't need it; this is equivalent to your current loop body:

```
s/apple/orange/i;
s/orange/apple/i;
```

However, we have to make two additions:

1. We want to substitute all occurrences, not just the first matched word. We can achieve this by using the `/g`  flag.
2. We want to do this in one substitution, so that the substitutions are not changed back.

We can do that by using a hash that maps matched strings to substitutions:

```
my %replacement = (
  apple  => 'orange',
  orange => 'apple',
);
while (<>) {
  s/(apple|orange)/$replacement{lc $1}/ig;
  print;
}
```

The `lc` lowercases the matched string; this is neccessary so that `Apple` will be substituted to `orange`. Keeping the casing (so that we would get `Orange`) can be achieved by removing case-insensitive matching and adding `Orange` and `Apple` to the replacement hash.

Now, if your hash has a large number of substitutions, we don't want to write the regex (just a lot of static alternatives) manually. We can create a correct regex from the hash like

```
my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %replacement;
while (<>) {
  s/($re)/$replacement{$1}/g;
}
```

The `quotemeta` escapes special characters so that you can match arbitrary strings literally.

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated The `qr//` quotes a regex. This is comfortable as the same escaping rules as for regexes apply. If I'd used a plain string, it would have beed `"\\Q$_\\E"` or rather `quotemeta($_)`. The `qr//` comes in handy when you need precompiled or composable regexes (it returns a regex object). The `map` applies an action to each item in the list to its right. It then returns the transformed items. The current item is in `$_`.

Comment: @amon: What `qr//` does is *compile* the string as a regex. Here there is no point as you convert it straight back to a string before it is used as a parameter to join. This is better written as `my $re = join '|', map quotemeta($_), keys %replacement`

Comment: (`$&` doesn't slow down matching any more than using captures. What it does is add the cost of captures to all patterns in the program, even if they don't use captures.)

Answer (score 3):

```
my %look = (
  "apple" => "orange",
  "orange" => "apple",
);
my $rx = join "|", keys %look;

while (<MYFILE>) {
  s! ($rx) !$look{lc($1)}!xgi;
}
```